# Using dictation in the command line (e.g. transcribe an audio recording to a text file)

Tags: command-line, voice-dictation

I have some audio recordings and would like to transcribe them into text files. I was wondering whether there is a command line tool that could use the built-in Dictation to do that? And if so, is there a known duration limit?

Answer (score 1):

Dictation only works in standard text input UI widgets. Terminal applications typically don't use them.

The time limit per submission for processing is 30 seconds.